# reactjs дублирующийся запросы fetch

Tags: reactjs

Есть вот такой код

```js
getinfo = async (e) => {
var userinfo = await fetch(`https://site.com?token=${token}`);
var data = await userinfo.json();
}
```

Но при его вызове из `render` запрос fetch повторяется два раза. Как это исправить?

Comment: Покажите код, где вы вызываете данную функцию. Если уж ванговать, то предположу, что вы ее в рендере запускаете, что ее дважды и вызывет. Используйте хуки `useState`, `useEffect`, чтобы убрать дублирование

Comment: @Dmitry да я из рендера его вызываю, сори что сначала не указал

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего вы используете `StrictMode`. По документации в строгом режиме происходит двойной вызов метода `render`. Попробуйте отключить `StrictMode`.

https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects

Comment: Я добавил `console.log` в начало `getinfo` и он вызывается один раз

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так, забросив саму функцию и ее вызов в `useEffect`

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

function your_component (){
  useEffect(()=>{
    const getinfo = async (e) => {
      var userinfo = await fetch(`https://site.com?token=${token}`);
      var data = await userinfo.json();
    };
    getinfo(e);
  },[])
  return(
    <Your_render_here />
  )
}
```

данный хук используется только в функциональных компонентах, но [здесь](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-classes-1) можно найти пример с использованием классов.
Важно, данное решение вызывается только после того как все зарендерится. Если необходимо использовать данный вызов при определенных условиях, то используется хук `useState()`

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function your_component (){
  const [state, setState] = useState(false);

  useEffect(()=>{
    ......
  },[state]);
  return(
    <Your_render_here />
  )
}
```

при такой конструкции при изменении состояния `state` переменной будет вызываться функция, которая находится внутри `useEffect`-конструкции